# Noetherian group rings

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, noetherian, amenability

I'm asking for an example of a finitely generated amenable group $G$ and a field $K$, such that the group ring $K[G]$ is not Noetherian.

Is it also possible to find a finitely generated amenable group $G$ and a field $K$ such that $K[G]$ does not even embed in a Noetherian ring?

Comment: If you want, I can move this question to MathOverflow.

Comment: I do not know if it is interesting enough, maybe such examples are well-known... but if you think it is the case, if is fine with me

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, see my answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/165039/does-gl-nz-have-a-noetherian-group-ring/165065#165065). It says that if the group $G$ is not noetherian (in the sense that every subgroup is f.g.) then $K[G]$ is not noetherian for any field $K$. Now pick, for instance, any non-virtually-polycyclic f.g. solvable group, such as solvable Baumslag-Solitar groups $BS(1,n)$ for $|n|\ge 2$, or a lamplighter group, to get an example.

The second question sounds more tricky. Indeed every [Ore domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore_condition) embeds into a division ring (this is noetherian!) and there are many torsion-free groups for which the group algebra is known to be an Ore domain. These include poly-(torsion-free abelian) groups, for instance the solvable Baumslag-Solitar groups. This does not answer your question, but this leads me to wonder if it could not be true that every group ring embeds into a noetherian ring (of course, not a division ring!).

Comment: thanks for your example! Regarding the second part, it may very well be true that any group ring embeds in a Noetherian ring but at least this is certainly not know (e.g., Kaplasky's stable finiteness conjecture would be trivial in that case)